# If $\alpha = \prod_{i = 1}^{\infty} a_i \in \bar{\Bbb{Q}}$ can we write $\alpha = a_n \alpha'$ with $\text{den}(\alpha) = \text{den}(\alpha')$?

Tags: number-theory, infinite-product

> If $\alpha$ is any algebraic number, there is an integer $d > 0$ such that $d\alpha$ is an algebraic integer, and the minimum such $d$ is called the *denominator* of $\alpha$, written $\text{den}(\alpha)$.

Now consider a sequence of algebraic integers $(a_i)$ such that
$$
\alpha = \prod_{i = 1}^{\infty} a_i
$$
is algebraic. I'm wondering if there are some nice sufficient conditions for the existence of an index $n$ such that $\alpha = a_n \alpha'$ with $\text{den}(\alpha) = \text{den}(\alpha')$. It would also be nice to know if we can choose $n$ such that $a_n \mathcal{O}_K$ and $\text{den}(\alpha) \mathcal{O}_K$ are coprime, where $K = \mathbb{Q}(a_n)$.

---

I tried to find some examples of $\alpha$ and play with those, but so far I came up short. I can see that the answer to both questions is positive for
$$
n = n^{\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} 1/2^i} = \prod_{i = 1}^{\infty} n^{1/2^i}
$$
with $n$ any fixed positive integer, but I couldn't even extend this to
$$
\alpha = \prod_{i = 1}^{\infty} n^{1/m_i}
$$
for any given sequence of integers $(m_i)$ such that the product converges. In general I only know that if $\alpha$ is irrational and algebraic, then $\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} 1/m_i$ cannot be in $\overline{\Bbb{Q}} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$ (as a consequence of [Baker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem)).

---

*Motivation:* Such a factorisation would imply a neat proof that some numbers, like [$\prod_{k=2}^{\infty} k^{1/2^{k-1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898405/is-sqrt-2-sqrt-3-sqrt-4-ldots-algebraic-or-transcendental), are transcendental.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Should this question be migrated to MO? Even after searching in the metas I really don't know how such a migration would work. On the other hand, maybe this question has an easy answer which I'm unable to see. I'm asking you since this seems to fit into your area of expertise...