# Nested Radicals with multiplication

Tags: calculus, radicals, nested-radicals

I think this one goes to section of nested radicals, I was trying to solve if for a couple of days now. Maybe you have some nice solution to this one.

$$\sqrt{1\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{4\sqrt{...}}}}}$$

I think it should converge. I computed with 1000 elements and 100000000 elements and got same result of 1.66169.

A more general case:
$$g(n)=\sqrt{n\sqrt{(n+1)\sqrt{(n+2)\sqrt{(n+3)\sqrt{...}}}}}$$

Has a very nice result of:
$$g(n+1)=\frac{g^2(n)}{n}$$

So solving simple case $g(1)$ would also solve more general one.

Edit: My question was if there was a smart way of calculating $\sqrt{1\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{4\sqrt{...}}}}}$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What does your first nested radical limit mean? Can you write a couple of terms of the sequence whose limit you are interested in? If you mean $x,x^{1(2},(x^{1/2})^{1/3},\dots$ for some initial $x>0$, then the limit is the same as $\lim_{N\to\infty}x^{1/N}$.

Comment: My guess is that the OP is asking for the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(2^{1/4}3^{1/8}\cdots n^{2^{-n}}\cdots\right)$$

Comment: some times your intuition of convergence may be wrong. For example: calculate the $1000000000000$ terms of the sequence $s_n=1+1/2+1/3+...+1/n$

Comment: Or worse: do the same with primes: $s_n=1/2+1/3+1/5+1/7+1/11+\dots+1/p_n$.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/745597).

Answer (score 8):

This is [Somos' quadratic recurrence constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somos'_quadratic_recurrence_constant) $($see [also](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SomossQuadraticRecurrenceConstant.html)$)$, for which no closed form is yet known. Its decimal expansion can be found [here](https://oeis.org/A112302). A similar expression, also lacking a known closed form, is the [nested radical constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html), whose digits can also be found on [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A072449). Hope this helps.

Comment: A similar question can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/745597).

Answer (score 7):

Since $g(1) = 1^{1/2} 2^{1/4} 3^{1/8} \cdots$, we can write $\log g(1)$ as an infinite sum. $$ \log g(1) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log k}{2^k}. $$

This series obviously converges since $\log k < 1.5^k$, but I doubt it would be expressed in terms of elementary functions. (See [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=sum%20(log%20n)%2F2%5En%20from%201%20to%20inf))